# Is there a known optimal solution for searching an ordered list with non-uniform query cost?

Tags: algorithms, discrete-optimization, operations-research

Let $D$ be the set of integers from $1$ to $n$ inclusive for $n \geq 1$, and let $$f(i) = \begin{cases}
  0& i \leq k \\ 
  i - k& i > k 
\end{cases}\,\,\,\forall\, i \in D$$ for some $k \in D$. That is, $f$ is a discrete unit ramp starting at some value $k$.

Suppose the value of $k$ is unknown *a priori*, but is distributed over $D$ with probability $p(k)$, and we wish to find $k$. To do this, we can query the value of $f(i)$ for as many values of $i$ as needed, but there are two "quirks":

1. the cost of querying the value of $f(i)$ is $i$ (that is, the cost of a query is proportional to the index being queried)
2. since $f$ is a unit ramp, any query where $i > k$ will give us the value of $k$

The total cost is the sum of all queries needed to identify $k$.

**My two questions are:**

1. Is there a known optimal algorithm for minimizing the expected total cost given uniform $p(k)$?
2. Is there a known optimal algorithm for minimizing the expected total cost given an arbitrary $p(k)$?

This problem has cropped up in a software routine I'm writing. I'd appreciate any advice or assistance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your "quirks" are based on a linear search.

Use a Binary search.

If k is ANY value where i > k, then why query i+n recursively starting with n=0 until k > 1? Since it's an already  ordered list you don't need to treat it like a series dependent on it's previous recursion. Why not just query the last element in the list? if it's not there then k doesn't exist?

If it is an ordered series and not an ordered list, then you're pretty much out of luck. That's just the nature of a series.

If it is a list, did you mean to say that k is the value of the smallest i where the value k is greater than it's index i?

In that case you don't have to go i+1 one by one until  your "k > i" condition returns true, do a binary search, use threads, or do both. Binary search is well documented, been around almost 100 years at least, so I'm not going to explain it here.

Using threads to speed it up should be intuitive if you know how to use some kind of parallel for or for each, nice linear speedup, but if not there are some good examples, probably even either some build in functors or templates or lambda functions in w/e language you're using.

It's just a linear speedup, time*cpu_cores plus maybe some benefit from using virtual cores or hyper threads, so it may or may not be that important to you especially if the machine has no idle cores to use, is often doing other critical work or w/e.

Comment: I suppose you could have a distribution of values where due to differences in rate of change of consecutive values that any rate of change between two consecutive values lower than 1 vs constant rate of change of i+1 of the index, then you might have a situation where i was greater than then less than and then later in the index again greater than it's value.

Comment: In that kind of data set where the rate of change of values of i and i+1 are less than 1 you would have to scan the whole list. Your only optimization that i can see would involve 1) using multiple threads or tasks and 2) be based on knowing the all rates of change of consecutive values, or at least how many times the values rate of change is less than the indexe's constant rate of change of one.

Comment: Just FYI I realize that's probably not realistic statistic to ask for for most any data sets, but if that is the case and you have all that information, you might have more success thinking of the index's steady slope and it's the data set as seperate linear equations, taking their derivatives (aka 1 for the index) and just finding points when those functions intersect.

Comment: The search wasn't limited to being linear, and I can think of numerous algorithms that would provide $O(n \log n)$ performance. I was wondering if there's a known "best" algorithm. A physical analogy would be trying to plumb the depth of a well with a winch that must be preset to a depth and lowers/raises a line at constant speed (say 1 m/s). You could start out by testing 20 m, say, which would cost 40 s. If the line came out wet, you could count the number of wet meters and deduce the depth of the well. If the line came out dry, you have to try again at a greater depth.